# import_script_from_url syntax

Tags: smartpy

i'd like to ask if it's possible to load another smart contract from an IPFS Hash or from a SmartPy url. What would be the best way to handle them with urls?

Contract A: https://smartpy.io/ide?cid=QmVPMCXXiUpe394zJFuKy2t5SeAviJzUWQsawL7z3WUVjJ&k=15243351510310b52b58

```
import smartpy as sp

B = sp.import_script_from_url('https://smartpy.io/ide?cid=Qmdwn3DijL1eSh8NVDUsuLNkv5G8XasHD7RzqymiwhXB6H&k=8cffde9f7bbe1d23e9eb')

class A(sp.Contract):
    def __init__(self, **kargs):
        self.init(**kargs)

    @sp.entry_point
    def x(self, params):
        pass
```

Contract B (it's almost the same given above): https://smartpy.io/ide?cid=QmNSdUmBL32eVp9dyB96eyBSbqtcGycb8hXcpTCNanhzMr&k=901c9fc94841b0611393

```
Error: invalid syntax

 SmartPy code line 3 (line 3)
   B = sp.import_script_from_url('https://smartpy.io/ide?cid=Qmdwn3DijL1eSh8NVDUsuLNkv5G8XasHD7RzqymiwhXB6H&k=8cffde9f7bbe1d23e9eb')
 SmartPy code, line 1 (line 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to import a contact already stored by the IDE, you can do the following:

**Import the following 2 contracts and name them ContractA and ContractB:**

ContractA => https://smartpy.io/ide?cid=QmQRQ7eBRw9AhfgMoXhMfEpwSasakE2HFCCxQdAgs1cyZR&k=3fa7c6befc039ee5bb36

ContractB => https://smartpy.io/ide?cid=QmaZSLA3zCUHGAQWWp3vJJyF9xQ4mUqMZi4hhEY4M3f147&k=4ec858e12568f3642fa1

**Then import contractB into ContractA with:**

`B = sp.import_stored_contract("ContractB")`

[image]

`sp.import_script_from_url` will only work for plain text files that have the raw content of the contract. For example https://pastebin.com/raw/aNEYng4w

Comment: it gives me network error ;< w the raw pastebin as an example

Comment: I think pastebin does not add CORS headers for other origins. You will have to use another host to provision the files.